# BootstrapValidator custom validation return message from language pack

Tags: javascript, bootstrapvalidator

```
if( value.match(/\d+/g) && value.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g) ) {
                return {
                    valid: true,
                }
            }

            return {
                valid: false,
                //need to return message from language pack
            }
//language pack(en_US.js)
account: {
            'default': 'Account must contain at leas 1 number & 1 english letter'
        }
```

I have an input use bootstrap validator, however I create my own validation

I need to return error message from language pack. anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
message : $.fn.bootstrapValidator.i18n.account.default

//language en_US.js add
account: {
            'default': 'Account must contain at leas 1 number & 1 english letter'
        }
```

I have found solution, please see above